# Mesos containerizer displays sensitive data via env variable in stdout

Tags: mesos

We are passing sensitive data to programs executed within mesos slaves via environment variables. It works alright except we notice that it can be seen in the first few lines of the `stdout` which is accessible in the `sandbox` web console.

We see something like this

```
Starting task 01c811c3-1ab2-46aa-a0c9-7b1481797f7f
/usr/libexec/mesos/mesos-containerizer launch --command="{"environment":{"variables":[{"name":"DEV_KEY","value":"**secret**"}]},"shell":true,"uris":[{"executable":true,"extract":false,"value":"http:\/\/box.in.my.company.com\/launch-alfred.sh"}],"value":".\/launch-alfred.sh"}" --help="false" --unshare_namespace_mnt="false"
```

Question - how do I not render that sensitive data in that line?

Comment: Take a look at [MESOS-7292](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-7292)

Comment: Thanks! I will _watch_ the ticket. As of now, it has not been taken up for resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of suggestions -

1. Consider using encryption of environment variable value & then pass it onto Containerizer.
2. Consider deploying a solution like [this](https://github.com/meltwater/secretary), if Vault solutions are too heavy. (Marathon centric solution).